# How do you say "How long..." in spanish

Tags: tiempo

Researching how to say *How long* in Spanish, I came across these three versions

> 1. ¿Cuánto tiempo...?
> 2. ¿Cuánto tiempo dura...?
> 3. ¿Cuánto dura...?

In the third case, I assume *tiempo* is understood. What I don't get is the function of the word **dura** (hard). Looking up the meaning of **dura** makes me every more confused.

Comment: *dura* comes from the verb *durar* (to have a duration, to last [a time], to take [a time]).  Note that *how long* could also refer to physical length, and then it would be a different word entirely.  I presume, of course, you mean to ask about asking how long something lasts or will take, correct?

Comment: Yes, but it now you have peaked my interest in finding out the distinction between both :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are *two* equivalent versions. “Cuánto” means literally “how much”, so to ask “how long” we say “cuánto tiempo” (“how much time”), and when the context makes the noun redundant we drop it just like an English speaker would:

> ¿Cuánto [tiempo] dura?
>
> ¿Cuánto [dinero] cuesta?
>
> ¿Cuánto [peso] pesa?
>
> ¿Cuánt[o/a distancia] hay de ... a ...? (note the use of the masculine form as neutral)

I often hear “qué” used instead of “cuánto”, but it's not as literal and it may depend on where you are.

Comment: +1. But I would not recommend using *qué* instead of *cuánto*, though you can sometimes hear it.

Comment: @Gorpik, it's not as literal but I hear it a lot around me. I'll add a note.

Comment: I've heard it, too. Your note is fine, since it is sometimes used; I just think it should not be recommended to a language learner. Again, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

*How long* in certain contexts can also be translated as *desde cuándo*, such as *How long have you lived in Massachusetts?*: *¿Desde cuándo vives en Massachusetts?* (in addition to *¿Cuánto tiempo has vivido en Masachusetts?*)

(I'm ignoring here the other meaning of *how long*, as in *How long is your flagpole?*)